# Keras model does not generalise

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to build a deep learning model on Keras for a test and I am not very good at this. I have a scaled dataset with 128 features and these correspond to 6 different classes.

I have already tried adding/deleting layers or using regularisation like dropout/l1/l2, My model learns and accuracy goes up so high. But accuracy on test set is around 15%.

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(128, activation='tanh', input_shape=(128,)))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(60, activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(20, activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(6, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='Nadam', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(train_X, train_y, epochs=20, batch_size=32, verbose=1)
```

```
6955/6955 [==============================] - 1s 109us/sample - loss: 1.5805 - acc: 0.3865
Epoch 2/20
6955/6955 [==============================] - 0s 71us/sample - loss: 1.1512 - acc: 0.6505
Epoch 3/20
6955/6955 [==============================] - 0s 71us/sample - loss: 0.9191 - acc: 0.7307
Epoch 4/20
6955/6955 [==============================] - 0s 67us/sample - loss: 0.7819 - acc: 0.7639
Epoch 5/20
6955/6955 [==============================] - 0s 66us/sample - loss: 0.6939 - acc: 0.7882
Epoch 6/20
6955/6955 [==============================] - 0s 69us/sample - loss: 0.6284 - acc: 0.8099
Epoch 7/20
6955/6955 [==============================] - 0s 70us/sample - loss: 0.5822 - acc: 0.8240
Epoch 8/20
6955/6955 [==============================] - 1s 73us/sample - loss: 0.5305 - acc: 0.8367
Epoch 9/20
6955/6955 [==============================] - 1s 75us/sample - loss: 0.5130 - acc: 0.8441
Epoch 10/20
6955/6955 [==============================] - 1s 75us/sample - loss: 0.4703 - acc: 0.8591
Epoch 11/20
6955/6955 [==============================] - 1s 73us/sample - loss: 0.4679 - acc: 0.8650
Epoch 12/20
6955/6955 [==============================] - 1s 77us/sample - loss: 0.4399 - acc: 0.8705
Epoch 13/20
6955/6955 [==============================] - 1s 80us/sample - loss: 0.4055 - acc: 0.8904
Epoch 14/20
6955/6955 [==============================] - 1s 77us/sample - loss: 0.3965 - acc: 0.8874
Epoch 15/20
6955/6955 [==============================] - 1s 77us/sample - loss: 0.3964 - acc: 0.8877
Epoch 16/20
6955/6955 [==============================] - 1s 77us/sample - loss: 0.3564 - acc: 0.9048
Epoch 17/20
6955/6955 [==============================] - 1s 80us/sample - loss: 0.3517 - acc: 0.9087
Epoch 18/20
6955/6955 [==============================] - 1s 78us/sample - loss: 0.3254 - acc: 0.9133
Epoch 19/20
6955/6955 [==============================] - 1s 78us/sample - loss: 0.3367 - acc: 0.9116
Epoch 20/20
6955/6955 [==============================] - 1s 76us/sample - loss: 0.3165 - acc: 0.9192
```

The result I am recieving `39%` With other models like GBM or XGB I can reach upto `85%`

What am I doing wrong? Any suggestions?

Comment: Your choice of sigmoid for the final layer activation implies a sample can belong to more than one classes. Is this really is the case, try `binary_crossentropy` loss. If each sample only has one label then switch to softmax activation on the last layer and stick with `categorical_crossentropy` loss.
Otherwise, is the class distribution similar between your training and test set?

Comment: I changed the last layer to `softmax` and it worked. Thanks a lot!

Comment: yaay! happy to help :)

Comment: i think it will be better with higher keep probability rate. can you change first dropout layer upto 0.75 and delete others